# How to rebuild children (& replay animations) after change in parent state

Tags: animation, state, flutter

My parent widget holds an `isLiked` `bool` field.

When the child widgets are initially built, they play their animation. Note the following snippet:

```
@override
void initState() {
    ...
    _animationController.forward();
}
```

I am accessing the parent's state using an `InheritedWidget`. I tried adding `_animationController.reset()` to `initState()`, but this didn't work either.

I think this child component is not being rebuilt when the parent state updates. I am using the following (reusable) code to pass state down the widget tree, as described in this [flutter reactive state article.](https://medium.com/@maksimrv/reactive-app-state-in-flutter-73f829bcf6a7)

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class Provider extends StatefulWidget {
  const Provider({this.data, this.child});

  static of(BuildContext context) {
    _InheritedProvider p =
        context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(_InheritedProvider);
    return p.data;
  }

  final data;
  final child;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _ProviderState();
}

class _ProviderState extends State<Provider> {
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    widget.data.addListener(didValueChange);
  }

  didValueChange() => setState(() {});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new _InheritedProvider(
      data: widget.data,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    widget.data.removeListener(didValueChange);
    super.dispose();
  }
}

class _InheritedProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  _InheritedProvider({this.data, this.child})
      : _dataValue = data.value,
        super(child: child);
  final data;
  final child;
  final _dataValue;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_InheritedProvider oldWidget) {
    return _dataValue != oldWidget._dataValue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your child widgets are being rebuilt, but their corresponding `State` objects aren't. `initState` is only called once, since the framework tries to reuse them when possible.  To be notified when this happens, you can use the `didUpdateWidget` lifecycle method.  For example, to restart your controller every time the configuration changes:

```
class MyState extends State<MyWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // do initial setup.
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(MyWidget oldWidget) {
     super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    // do subsequent updates.
  }

  ...
}
```

You could even compare the members on `widget` and `oldWidget` and conditionally restart or stop your animation.